# JQuery selectors - using html snippets as "context" in filter and find

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

A quick question about using `context` with Jquery selectors:

I'm trying to grab the text from a div element that has `id="time"`. Can a HTML snippet be used as `context` in the following:

```
// An AJAX request here returns a HTML snippet "response":

var myTime = $("#time", response).text();
```

The reason I'm doing this is that I want the `time` variable from within the html held in `response`, but don't want the overhead of loading all of the html into the DOM first. (it's a large amount of html).

Comment: Not according to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context.

Comment: Okay fair enough, but do you know of an alternative method for using a JQuery selector on an html snippet without loading it into the div first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments what I understand is the response is `<span id="time">blah blah</span>` which means the element `time` is the root variable itself, that is why the child lookup is not working.

```
var response = '<span id="time">blah blah</span>';
var myTime = $(response).text(); // Or $(response).filter("#time").text();
alert(myTime)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rccLL/3/)

This method uses `filter()` rather than `find()`, the difference being:

`filter()` – search through the passed element set

`find()` – search through all the *child* elements only.

Comment: Yes I realise that my code is equivalent to this, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: @WheretheresaWill seems to be fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rccLL/ , can you share how the html is loaded and the html content

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rccLL/1/ is my updated version with double quotes instead of single - with this change it no longer works!

Comment: @WheretheresaWill Because you are getting a syntax error... Put single quotes around the string or escape your double quotes

Comment: My response seems to have double quotes around it - but I'm not sure if that's just due to google chrome's presentation of the string... So when I hover over the variable in chrome's dev tools it shows me `"<span id="time">blah blah</span>"` *with* the quotes.

Comment: Bloody legend!  Thanks - this works perfectly.  I've just had a quick look at the differences: 


1 - filter() – search through all the elements.
2 - find() – search through all the child elements only.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it?

```
$("#time", "<div><span id=time></span></div>")[0].id //returns 'time'
```

From the jQuery source code:

```
// HANDLE: $(expr, context) 
// (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
} else {
    return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );
}
```

so valid selectors should work in the context parameter.  Personally, I prefer using `find` to begin with because it keeps all the selectors in the same order instead of `$("second > third", "first");`

Comment: I tried this with my `response` from the ajax request and it is undefined... There must be some difference between my response and a regular string...